# etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured (kubernetes multi-master)

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to kubernetes and I am working on creating multi-master-kubernetes with 2 masters nodes.

 Could anyone explain why when I execute the command

`ETCDCTL_API=2 etcdctl member list`, I get:

> etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured;

And when I execute `ETCDCTL_API=2 etcdctl --ca-file=/etc/etcd/ca.pem --cert-file=/etc/etcd/kubernetes.pem --key-file=/etc/etcd/kubernetes-key.pem member list`, I get this result:

> cc59f69db7afb8fc: name=x peerURLs=https://x.x.x.x:2380
>   clientURLs=https://x.x.x.x:2379 isLeader=false
>   
> e91f43559989b2a6: name=y peerURLs=https://x.x.x.x:2380
>   clientURLs=https://x.x.x.x:2379 isLeader=true

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a stupidity of me for not paying attention to etcdctl version. In my case, I had to use 
`ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl member list`

And do not forget to export the env.